#  How can I reset the answers of the security questions of my Apple ID?

Tags: password, apple-id

I forgot the answers of the security questions. Not that I seriously need to do it now, but there might be a problem if I need to answer those in future.

I still remember my password.

How can I reset the answers of the security questions?

Comment: Are you talking about your AppleID? If so you remember your password you can edit these questions at appleid.apple.com

Comment: I can't. I've to answer the old questions first to edit them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to reset your Apple ID security questions online after the Mat Honan hack and its aftermath.

I was able to reset my security questions by calling Apple Support on the phone, *provided I could remember at least one out of three*.

However if you can't remember any of the three, you might have trouble.

Comment: That means I have to live with forgotten answers, though I can always reset password through email, if I ever forgot it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: if you ever need to provision a new iOS device, it will force you to answer the security questions. So you'll be stuck eventually.

Comment: This scenario very likely may have changed over time: when this happened to me recently, Apple Support sent a code to my iPhone, and had me generate and read back a code on the Apple ID site while signed in. This was apparently sufficient authentication for them to reset my questions, despite my not remembering any.

Comment: I rarely down vote but since there are several questions duped back here and this is not the best answer (seven years later) it's what I can do. `iforgot.apple.com` seems to be the place to go now, however it didn't work for me :-(  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8APVg.png

Comment: Just called Apple Support, and was told this is something they no longer do.

Comment: Just did this yesterday.  they don't do this anymore.  you either know your questions, or can get a reset link to your recovery email, or you have a linked device. without one of those, they provide no assistance, just apologies. if you do have or can link a device, you can add your id to the device, use it for 'proof of identity', and reset the questions with no more than your username and password.

Answer (score 3):

The reset procedure for security questions is here: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201485

- https://iforgot.apple.com/

It's one of the [things you are recommended to do if you think your AppleID is compromised.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204145)

Below are more details and screen shots from a while back, but the links above have current information as well as discussion on how to get support in person and newer developments like [Two Factor Authentication](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204915) and 
using another trusted device.

---

If you know your password to your Apple ID and have set up a second email address, you can reset your security questions by logging into the web site https://appleid.apple.com even if you can't answer the security questions that normally are required to make changes to the existing security questions.

Once you have logged in, click 'Password and Security'.  Then click/tap the link in the lower right that says **Forgot your answers? Send reset security info email to m * * * *@monsters.edu**

[image: reset security info for Apple ID]

You will get an email with a link to reset not only the security questions and answers, but correct your birth date which can be used to verity your identity when you are calling Apple or trying to reset a password.

### [image: Email for Apple ID security info reset]

I have an Apple ID with a recovery email, so perhaps if you have not entered that second email, you might not be able to send the reset email and might need to [contact Apple directly](http://www.apple.com/support/appleid) for help with your Apple ID. I know of people that have gotten things reset over the phone even after the [Mat Honan incident](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2012/08/apple-amazon-mat-honan-hacking/) where his account was compromised over the phone with Apple's assistance.

Comment: Jeff's answer is wrong.  This one is right (I just added a missing step that may have tripped up Creator.  
I get the "Forgot your answers? Send reset security info email to..." message.
(Or perhaps Jeff was treated differently because he was using a browser/from an IP he hadn't used with his Apple ID before.)

Comment: Jeff's answer isn't wrong for me.  I can get in, change my password, hell, even update my credit card information after being logged into the App Store.  But it won't let me change my security questions without already knowing my security questions.

Comment: both answers are not working for me: `iforgot.apple.com` seems to be the place to go now, however it didn't work for me :-(  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8APVg.png I'll try walking in to one of the Apple stores wearing a mask that looks like Jeff Atwood's avatar.

Comment: this is the right answer as long as you have access to the recovery email. in a number of cases being reported, the accounts are really old, they don't recall ever setting security questions (was there a point where they were just forced onto accounts?), and the recovery email is no longer valid.  Customer service tells me those are completely unrecoverable unless you have a device. if you do, you can follow the directions with just a login/password here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/430093/289638

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to remember the answers to your security questions to edit them. As long as you know the password to the account you can log at AppleID.apple.com at the Manage Account link and click on the security and passwords option on the left and change your questions. (I've just tested it on my account with no problems).

Comment: When I click on Password and Security option, it just ask me two of the three security question and a continue button, I can't go through them, unless I answer them.

Comment: That's quite interesting. I logged into my other AppleID (a non iCloud one) and I got the same as you. I guess you'll have to call AppleCare if you don't know the answers - although I hear they've suspended any password resets over the phone for the moment.

Comment: Nope, you have to answer the questions to change them. Which is impossible if you can't remember them...