# How to reset Apple ID PW without knowing original PW and answer to security question?

Tags: password

I cannot use iCloud since I forgot the password for my MACBookPro original APPLE ID. The email address associated with this ID is no longer valid and the security question was never set up. How do i reset the password? I want to change the ID and use new PW to access icloud.

Comment: I can't see why this was closed - the user is asking a very straightforward "how do I" question. They were not seeking a comparison or recommendation.

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60656/how-can-i-reset-the-answers-of-the-security-questions-of-my-apple-id

Answer (score 1):

"[If you forgot your Apple ID password](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5787)" on Apple's support website provides the steps to reset your password, however you have stated you do have not access to the original email address and a security question was not set up.

Therefore you will need to contact Apple directly. "[Contacting Apple for help with Apple ID account security](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT5699)" provides a country-by-country list of contacts for Apple ID password issues.